# How to use TA1 of P1.6 without also using it on P1.2 on MSP430F1101

Tags: c, timer, msp430, code

I have been struggling for a lot of time now, training to use the pwm function on pin 1.6 of the microcontroller. For P1SEL=BIT2, it is correctly using TA1 on P1.2, but for P1SEL=BIT6 it is not using P1.6. I have tired other combinations too, it only works(as far as I know) P1SEL=0xF4, but that also uses P1.2...
I hope I was somewhat clear in my explanation.
EDIT1: I used Proteus 8 for simulation and IAR Embedded Workbench IDE as IDE

```
#include "msp430f1101.h"

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned int u16;

u8 pwm_preffered_idx(const u16 frecv)
{
  if(frecv < 2)
  {
    return ID_0;
  }
  if(frecv < 4)
  {
    return ID_1;
  }
  if(frecv < 7)
  {
    return ID_2;
  }
  else
  {
    return ID_3;
  }
}

u8 pwm_preffered_idx_div(const u16 frecv)
{
  if(frecv < 2)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  if(frecv < 4)
  {
    return 2;
  }
  if(frecv < 7)
  {
    return 4;
  }
  else
  {
    return 8;
  }
}

void pwm(const u16 frecv,const u8 fu, const u8 pin)
{ 
  P1DIR=0;
  P1SEL= ~BIT2;
  TACCR0=800000/(frecv*pwm_preffered_idx_div(frecv)) - 1;
  TACCR1=((TACCR0+1) * (100-fu))/100;
  TACTL=( TASSEL_2 | pwm_preffered_idx(frecv) | MC_1 ); //SMCLK | DIV/1 | Up mode
  TACCTL1=OUTMOD_3; //Set/reset
}

int main( void )
{
  // Stop watchdog timer to prevent time out reset
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
  
  pwm(1000, 10, 12);
  
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If I remember right from my experiences of MSP430, you won't be able to use it as it is the timerA compare, you want the timerA capture. Try using P1.3 with TA2, or P2.2. I would have written an answer, but this was just from my memory of when I had similar issues and I don't have the time to trawl through the user guides at the moment for why it works like that!

Answer (score 0):

Your bit operations are wrong.

```
  P1DIR=0;
```

This configures all eight P1.x pins as inputs.

```
  P1SEL= ~BIT2;
```

This configures all P1.x pins except P1.2 for the module function; P1.2 is GPIO.

To output the PWM signal to P1.2, you need:

```
P1DIR |= BIT2;
P1SEL |= BIT2;
```

To output the PWM signal to P1.6, you need:

```
P1DIR |= BIT6;
P1SEL |= BIT6;
```

Please note that P1.2 can be used as both timer input or output, while P1.6 can be used only as timer output (see pages 26/27 of the datasheet).